# Disable swiftmailer per Controller action

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I know i can disable e-mail delivery in my config file by setting:

```
swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery: true
```

but i got a specific controller action where i'd like to disable email delivery through swiftmailer. Is there any way to do this?